# Laravel 5 It's not saving to database but there is no error?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-validation

I'm using laravel 5.5 and try to save my blog post's comments to the database. When I tried this, it's not saving to database and not give any error?

(I add a new comment, click send, redirect me same page. But not save comment to database..)

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request, $post_id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'comment' => 'required'
    ]);

    $post = Post::find($post_id);

    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->name = $request->name;
    $comment->email = $request->email;
    $comment->comment = $request->comment;
    $comment->approved = true;
    $comment->posts()->associate($post);
    $comment->save;

    return redirect()->route('post_slug',$post->slug);
}
```

Comment: Like someone said below, you'd be using ->save(). Otherwise it's taken as a property reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have comment saved and you are redirected to same page, I assume you don't have `name`, `email` or `comment` fields filled in. This is how validation works - if it fails, you will be redirected to previous url, so make sure you are displaying errors from validation to see what's going on.

**EDIT**

And one more thing - instead of `->save` you shuould use `->save()`  and move associating post at the end so instead of:

```
$comment->posts()->associate($post);
$comment->save;
```

you should use:

```
$comment->save();
$comment->posts()->associate($post);
```

and probably it's reasonable to use transaction to save those into database.

When you used `->save` you actually accessed attribute of model and haven't run model saving.

Comment: Maybe you have typo in field name in your form? You can look at `laravel.log` but in case this route was hit and redirection was made it should be empty. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#working-with-error-messages you have section about displaying error messages (obviously use Blade syntax if you using Blade)

Comment: .. How can I miss that..  I fixed but now we have new sweet error :) General error: 1364 Field 'post_id' doesn't have a default value..

Comment: Can one comment be assigned to multiple posts? I'm asking because you have this `posts` relationship and more reasonable would be having `post` relationship assuming comment is assigned to single post with `belongsTo` relationship

Comment: Nope, its just another type. I didin't mean assigned to multiple posts. Already use belongsTo releationship

Comment: @HasanTıngır So is `post_id` in `$fillable` property?

Comment: Try to add into your model `protected $fillable = ['post_id'];`

Comment: You should be able to use `$post->comments()->save($comment)` to make the association.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Eloquent provides convenient methods for adding new models to relationships, when you using it, with save() method it should look like that:

```
$comment = new App\Comment([
'name' => $request->name,
'email' => $request->email,
'comment' => $request->comment,
'approved' => true
]);

$post = App\Post::find($post_id);
$post->comments()->save($comment);
```

Or the proper way is to use create() method which accepts an array of attributes, creates a model, and inserts it into the database. For example:

```
$post = App\Post::find($post_id);

$comment = $post->comments()->create([
'name' => $request->name,
'email' => $request->email,
'comment' => $request->comment,
'approved' => true
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding the parameter to $fillable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).